# VueJs useSlots property returns error on array.map()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I created a reusable component for tabs in vuejs

it works if I use the `Tab` component like this.
App.vue

```
<Tabs>
  <Tab title="Tab 1"></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

However if try to loop the `Tab` component using `v-for` it returns an error within the `Tab` component.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')`

```
<Tabs>
<Tab title="Tab 1" v-for="(car, counter) in cars" v-bind:key="counter"></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Here is the `Tab` component's `<script setup>` tag

```
<script setup>
import { ref, useSlots, provide } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();
const tabTitles = ref(slots.default().map((tab) => tab.props.title));

const selectedTitle = ref(tabTitles.value[0]);

provide("selectedTitle", selectedTitle)

</script>
```

Tried to use for loop so that I can loop the `Tab` component dynamically.

How should I declare, so I can use `Tab` component within a `v-for` ?

`const tabTitles = ref(slots.default().map((tab) => tab.props.title));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you can change the value of `title` to match the counted array:

```js
<Tabs>
  <Tab v-for="(car, counter) in cars" :key="counter" :title="car.title"></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Make sure you change the `cars` array to know include the titles:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, useSlots, provide } from "vue";

const slots = useSlots();
const cars = ref([
  { title: "Tab 1" },
  { title: "Tab 2" },
  { title: "Tab 3" },
]);

provide("selectedTitle", cars[0].title);
</script>
```

Comment: I was to use my Tab component inside by fetching the component title props like this 
`const tabTitles = computed(   
    () => slots.default()[0].children.map((tab) => tab.props.title) 
)`